# Getting wrong value for area of geometry using Spatialite?

Tags: geometry, spatialite, area

I am trying to implement a measuring tool on apple maps for IPAD. As a part of that i collect all the touch points on the map into an array and constructing a geometry object from that and then calculating the length and area of the geometry using Spatialite.

Now my problem is that i am getting the length calculated correctly but the area is not calculated correctly

Below is the query for calculating length of geometry

**`SELECT Length(Transform(GeomFromText('POLYGON((32.653995 39.754341,32.654217 39.754127,32.653842 39.753991,32.653647 39.754207,32.653995 39.754341))',4326),3857))`**

Expected value is around 131 and Query result is 132.

Below is the query for calculating area of geometry.

**`SELECT Area(Transform(GeomFromText('POLYGON((32.653995 39.754341,32.654217 39.754127,32.653842 39.753991,32.653647 39.754207,32.653995 39.754341))',4326),3857))`**

Expected value is around **1020 Sqm** but Query result is **1706 Sqm**.

**Note: all points are geo referenced to Turkey region**

Why is this happening?

Comment: Web mercator (3857) doesn't preserve areas. Mercator designed his projection for navigators, so it preserves angles. You need a different projection.

Comment: Thanks it worked when i tried with EPSG:2321 (Projected crs for Turkey) instead of 3857.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by re projecting the coordinates from 4326 to 2321 (projected crs for Turkey region) instead of 3857.